# Self reference in generics

Tags: typescript

How can one self reference in generics?

How can one get type `C` below to return `{ a: C }`?

```js
// self reference ok
type A = { a: A }

// generic reference ok
type B<T> = { a: T }

// self reference not ok
type C = B<C> // should be { a: C }
```

This is useful if type `C` is composed of lower order objects, that sometimes return `this` which is `C`

Comment: As written, this is not possible (obviously you could just rewrite `C` as similar to `A` for the example) due to a design limitation in TypeScript; see [ms/TS#41164](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164). Is there some specific use case that you need to support?  If so you might want to [edit] to ask about it; otherwise this will just get a "no, sorry" answer with a link to github.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz.  The use case is object inheritance / composition.  I want to avoid duplicating the typing for each child object.  All base object methods that return `this` must be redefined at the top level as only at that level can it reference itself.  This creates a lot of duplication.

So I've got a verbose solution, but was hoping for a smarter/more concise solution.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question with a *specific* use case as a [mre]?  Maybe there's some other easier-to-write recursive syntax?  Not sure

Comment: @jcalz: I created [this](https://tsplay.dev/wE7Pvm) code to hopefully better illustrate the problem I'm trying to solve.   If you think there is value in editing the question to this more specific and more detailed example, I will do so.

Comment: I haven't found anything that works well for your use case.  If nobody else does then I might come back and post the "no sorry" answer with a link to ms/TS#41164

Answer (score 0):

I probably worded this question badly.  But I've just discovered the solution to my problem:  `interface` allows one to reference `this`.

So the solution was:

```js
interface A {
  that: this // this is the magic
  type: 'a'
}

interface C extends A {
  type: 'c'
}

const c:C
const c1 = c.that.type // 'c'
```